# Get list of interactive functions in Elisp/Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a bunch of my interactive functions with a prefix, say *zb/" (e.g. "zb/create-temp-buffer"). I am a bit tired every time to type in **M-x** interaction this prefix of a command I like to run.

To automate this I'd like to retrieve a list of all my interactive functions and show them through **ido-completing-read** (*btw, possibly there are other alternative and modern ways to create input with predefined items and autocompletion?*). But I did not manage to find how to retrieve a such list. Could you please give me a cue how to achieve this?

List of all available interactive functions will be enough; to filter is not an issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function for selection

```
(defun eab/select-zb/ ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively
   (intern
    (ido-completing-read "M-x zb/"
             (mapcar 'symbol-name (apropos-internal "^zb/"))))))
```

Comment: Perfect! *apropos-internal* was a keyword I looked for.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe give [Smex](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Smex) a try?

> Smex is a M-x enhancement for Emacs. Built on top of Ido, it provides a convenient interface to your recently and most frequently used commands. And to all the other commands, too.

Comment: Thanks for letting know about Smex but it requires a time for comprehension; on the other side there is a built-in instrument for this.

Answer (score 1):

You say *"possibly there are other alternative and modern ways to create input with predefined items and autocompletion?"*.

1. Use [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) and just bind `icicle-must-match-regexp`:

```
    (defun zb/ ()
      (interactive)
      (let ((icicle-must-match-regexp  "^zb/"))
        (call-interactively (intern (completing-read "zb/ command: " obarray 'commandp t)))))
```

1. You can also do it with vanilla Emacs and without Ido:

```
    (defun zb/ ()
      (interactive)
      (call-interactively
        (intern (completing-read
                 "zb/ command: "
                 obarray
                 (lambda (cmd)
                   (and (commandp cmd)  (string-match-p "^zb/" (symbol-name cmd))))
                 t))))
```

Or do as @artscan suggested: use `apropos-internal` to match the regexp.  IOW, either let `completing-read` do the matching or match first using `apropos-internal`.  You can pass the `commandp` predicate to `apropos-internal` as well.